# Can a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ map a closed but not open set into an open but not closed set?

Tags: real-analysis

Can a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ map a closed but not open set into open but not closed set?

I think not, because I tried a lot of examples that failed, but am unable to prove.

What I concluded is if $f(A)$ is open, then $f^{-1}(f(A))$ is an open set that contains the closed set $A$. But how would this lead to a proof?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the reverse mapping, take $f:(0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ given by $f(x)=x^x-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous function can map $[0, \infty)$ into $(0, \infty)$. Try making the graph of the function oscillate up and down above the x-axis. As $x \to \infty$, make the tops of the waves go to infinity and the bottoms of the waves get closer and closer to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks! Following your suggestion, I was capable of draw a graph that works. But I am not being able to find an expression for such a function.

Comment: @user1618 How about $f(x)=\arctan x\sin x$ or $g(x)=\frac{x^2\sin x}{1+x^2}$ mapping $[0,\infty)$ onto an open interval?